# Azure Logic Apps - Connect to On-Premise CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic app that needs to connect to an on-premise Dynamics CRM instance.
I'd like to use the "Dynamics 365" connector so I had a look at this article

- [Connect to data sources on premises from logic apps with on-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection)

But I can't see CRM as part of the supported data source.

For the moment, I plan to connect directly to CRM Sql Server database (available from the data gateway) but I am wondering if there is any workaround to use "Dynamics 365" connector to connect to an on-premise Dynamics CRM instance?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the CRM connector does not support the on-prem data gateway. Another option is to use Custom Connectors and wrap your CRM Soap endpoints with it.

Custom Connectors support the on-prem data gateway, thus you can wrap your CRM Soap Endpoints with the Custom Connector and use either SOAP to REST or SOAP pass-through.

This is still in preview and the team are still working on the documentation, but it works :)

HTH

Comment: Thanks, for the moment, I used an azure function to connec to CRM. I will have a look at your solution.